# What's the state-of-the-art, word-level forced alignment tool that is ok to use commercially?

Tags: transcription, software, speech-recognition

Forced alignment = synchronize audio and text. I'm looking for word-level forced alignment.

I see many forced alignment tools:

- https://github.com/topics/forced-alignment
- https://github.com/pettarin/forced-alignment-tools

What's the state-of-the-art, word-level  forced alignment tool that is ok to use commercially?

Comment: Downvoters, please explain yourselves.  This is a concrete, on-topic question from a formidable builder in the field of NLP.